# convert Windows Forms Application in C++ to executable file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS10 C++ and try to convert Windows Forms Application project to executable file: this what I did
select project-> properties -> configuration properties -> C/C++
   -> Code Generation -> Runtime library

then I select Multi-threaded Debug(/MTd)

when I built my project I got the following error

[image: error message]

Comment: A Windows Forms Application *is* an executable. Hello.

Comment: It's getting to the point I'm not going to even bother waiting for the planet to stop spinning before I get off.

Comment: I need to convert it to exe files, runnable on most Windows computers (without .net framework)

Comment: All versions of Windows since Windows Vista come with the .NET Framework installed, so you should be able to use .NET unless your application must be compatible with some really old versions of Windows (pre Windows XP). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Forms application depends on classes from the .NET Framework Base Class Library. To develop a Windows desktop application in C++ that does NOT depend on .NET, you should use the project template for a Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) Application instead. This type of project will compile as a native .exe, instead of a .NET assembly. (By the way, not sure why you would still be using Visual Studio 2010 for C++ development, when the free VS 2015 Community Edition fully supports C++11 and many features of C++14. I do not yet recommend VS 2017 however, since it is still very buggy for C++ development.)

EDIT: In Visual Studio 2017, there is another option (which was not available in VS 2015). If you choose the Windows Desktop Application project template, you will get a project that depends on neither .NET (aka CLR support) nor MFC. I have never tried this approach, but on the surface, it looks very similar to MFC. Again, so far I have found VS 2017 for C++ to be very buggy, so you might have a better experience using MFC in VS 2015 instead.